# Fancybox gallery with image map

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am trying to create a `fancybox` gallery using image maps. The `html/iframes` open but I can't get the gallery working.

I tried:

```
<area class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery"
```

and also tried:

```
<area class="fancybox" rel="gallery"
```

However, the previous and next buttons are not appearing.

Below is my javascript:

```
 $('map > area.fancybox').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
       $.fancybox({
            'href' : url,
        'type' : 'iframe'
            });
    });
```

I noticed it does seem to work if I manually add my gallery as a group, But then I will have to do a bit of manipulation to get the gallery order working?

```
$('map > area.fancybox').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log($(this).attr('rel'));
        $.fancybox([{
            'href' : url,
            'type' : 'iframe'
            },
            {
            'href' : 'class.cfm',
            'type' : 'iframe'
            },
            {
            'href' : 'explore.cfm',
            'type' : 'iframe'
            }]
            );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('map').find('area.fancybox').click(function()
    {
        var self = this;
        if( $(self).attr('href') != undefined || $(self).attr('href').length > 1 )
        {
            $.fancybox({
                href    :    $(self).attr('href'),
                type    :    'iframe'
            });
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('Ups!!');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Bye!

Comment: Um, not sure how this helps find the "gallery" property, can you explain a bit further?

Comment: attr( 'data-fancybox-group' ) , attr( 'rel' ), etc...  you should find the code by itself, if not using ATTR

Comment: But...my href (link) is working, just not the links before or after...the code above looks like it's doing a check on the current link, so how does this help with the gallery issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but maybe it will help someone.

With the latest version of fancybox, you can modify the "`groupAttr`" option :

```
$("#img_map area").fancybox({
    groupAttr : "alt"
});
```

Use alt as a "grouper" instead of rel, this works for image maps.

Cheers.